# Point3D and NumberFormatInfo

Tags: c#

I am trying to print a list of Point3D. However I don't want them to be printed with the maximal number of decimal digits. I want to be able to control this.

So I tried

```
Point3D loc = new Point3D(x,y,z);
var formatter = new NumberFormatInfo();
formatter.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
return loc.ToString(formatter);
```

But this didn't work and the point was still printed with too many decimal digits.

I would also like to do the same for other data structures that contain double members. I guess that the solution will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works with `Point3D` by using the explicit interface implementation of `IFormattable`. According to the docs, it's a method intended for internal uses, so you *might* be better off calling `String.Format` yourself with the point's coordinates instead of relying on this.

Here goes:

```
Point3D point3D = new Point3D(4.5545511, 3.14333, 9.99811);
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
NumberFormatInfo format = new NumberFormatInfo();
format.NumberDecimalDigits = 1;
string result = ((IFormattable)point3D).ToString("n",format);
//Outputs: "4.6,3.1,10.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify the format for every coordinate:

```
return loc.x.ToString(formatter) + "" + loc.y.ToString(formatter) + "" + loc.z.ToString(formatter)
```

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. What's the point of having a ToString() for Point3D if I end up implementing it explicitly each time I want to print a point?

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
Point3D loc = new Point3D(x, y, z);

var formatter = new NumberFormatInfo();
formatter.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;

return loc.ToString(null, formatter);
```

It uses [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344617.aspx) overloaded method. Unfortunately, I cannot test this code to be sure. Another way is to have a custom formatter class that contains all your formatting informations because, once instantiated, you can call your formatting functions for more than one object. I would advise you against overloading types like this one because they are (and should remain) [plain data objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure).

```
class Point3DFormatter
{
    public string Point3DFormat { get; set; }

    public Point3DFormatter()
    {
        Point3DFormat = "{0:0.00} {0:0.00} {0:0.00}";
    }

    string Format(Point3D point)
    {
        return string.Format(Point3DFormat, point.X, point.Y, point.Z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the style I have used for a long time now and it works well:

```
public struct Point3D : IFormattable
{
    public static string DefaultFormat = "F3";
    public float x,y,z;
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        string fmt = "({0:#},{1:#},{2:#})".Replace("#", format);
        return string.Format(formatProvider, fmt, x, y, z);
    }

    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        return ToString(format, null);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(DefaultFormat);
    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point3D A = new Point3D() { x = (float)Math.PI, y = (float)(-4 / Math.PI), z = (float)(0.005 * Math.PI) };

        Debug.WriteLine(A.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine(A.ToString("F2"));
    }
```

Prints out the following

```
(3.142,-1.273,0.016)
(3.14,-1.27,0.02)
```

Comment: The OP is clearly trying to use the WPF `Point3D` struct, and not write a new one :-)

Comment: Then is should be tagged as such. In any case, he can use the `string.Format(formatProvider, fmt, x, y, z);` function to perform his struct to string conversion.